Unsupported Locale setting error when running Azure pipelines
I am getting this below error snippet when I try to run pipeline build from Azure.
2024-06-18T06:02:45.1075555Z Your configuration files at build have not been touched.
2024-06-18T06:02:45.3914362Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-06-18T06:02:45.3915081Z   File "/build/sources/poky/bitbake/bin/bitbake", line 28, in <module>
2024-06-18T06:02:45.3915488Z     bb.utils.check_system_locale()
2024-06-18T06:02:45.3915863Z   File "/build/sources/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/utils.py", line 619, in check_system_locale
2024-06-18T06:02:45.3916530Z     locale.setlocale(locale.LC_CTYPE, default_locale)
2024-06-18T06:02:45.3916923Z   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/locale.py", line 620, in setlocale
2024-06-18T06:02:45.3917257Z     return _setlocale(category, locale)
2024-06-18T06:02:45.3917582Z locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
2024-06-18T06:02:45.5578186Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-06-18T06:02:45.5578712Z   File "/build/sources/poky/bitbake/bin/bitbake", line 28, in <module>
2024-06-18T06:02:45.5579048Z     bb.utils.check_system_locale()
2024-06-18T06:02:45.5579380Z   File "/build/sources/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/utils.py", line 619, in check_system_locale
2024-06-18T06:02:45.5579767Z     locale.setlocale(locale.LC_CTYPE, default_locale)
2024-06-18T06:02:45.5580111Z   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/locale.py", line 620, in setlocale
2024-06-18T06:02:45.5580420Z     return _setlocale(category, locale)
2024-06-18T06:02:45.5580696Z locale.Error: unsupported locale setting

I followed these links and have set locale correctly.
Output of locale:
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_IN:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

Output of locale -a:
C
C.utf8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IL
en_IL.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US
en_US.iso88591
en_US.iso885915
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
POSIX

in /etc/default/locale, /etc/locale-gen I can see the "en_US.UTF-8" correctly.
I have also tried locale-gen, sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales as per the attached links.
Locally on the server/terminal, I am able to run bitbake. I can see the correct LC_CTYPE/LC_ALL variables/values being set/reflecting correctly.
bitbake machine1-image works correctly when I login to the terminal.
But when I queue the build from Azure pipeline, it fails with the error.
**

Links Followed:

**
Problem with locale: "Setting locale failed."
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65525716/why-do-i-get-a-locale-error-even-though-it-is-set
how to set locale correctly manually?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42090237/change-locale-setting-in-yocto?rq=3
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78006534/python-locale-raising-unsupported-locale-setting
Misc Details:
IBM server.
22.04LTS
Kirkstone/Yocto

After much digging, I removed the lines present in /etc/environment, /etc/locale.gen and /etc/default/locale
Ran these commands:
sudo localectl set-locale LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
sudo reboot now

The issue has been resolved for now.
